# How many times trigger in MySQL is called?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I have a trigger on INSERT in MySQL 5.1. I want to know, how many times per second is it called. How can I do this?

Comment: question is not very clear. please include codes and elaborate your question

Comment: I know how many queries per second are executed. I want to know the same characteristics for trigger - how many times per second this procedure is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to keep inserting into a table.

```
INSERT INTO trigger_log(query) VALUES(?)
```

This table has a datetime column that will automatically be updated, then you can do various queries to determine how many times/minute or hour, what period had the highest number of calls, etc.

Otherwise just update a table that has a column for day, hour, min, counter and just increment the counter for the current day/hour/min.

I don't like the second one as much as there is so much potential information being lost, but it would do what you want also.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly cound the number of triggers on the inserts. You could analyse the logfiles or you could alter your trigger (as the trigger acts on insert) to write an entry in a log table with auto_increment id and datetime. You can then analyze this table for any statistics.